# How to handle a form close event from another form (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a Form1, when we close that Form1 and Form2 displays and I have added 2 Labels, "Are you sure?" and "Do you really want to exit?" and there are 3 buttons called "Yes", "No" and "I don't care". I know how to handle a closing form event using a message box it's:

```
    MessageBox("Do you really want to exit?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
e.Cancel = True

Else

e.Cancel = False
```

But I don't know how to stop closing Form1 from Form2. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that the only way to stop closing a form is using ``e As _
   System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs` of the formClosing event.

Comment: Set form1.visible = false. while form2 closing event execute Application.ExitThread() code that is easy way solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how I would go about solving this problem, use this code in Form1:

```
Public Class Form1
    'handle the Closing event of Form1 to be able to cancel the closing
    Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        'if Form2 returns a dialog result of Cancel, cancel the closing operation, otherwise let it continue
        If Form2.ShowDialog = DialogResult.Cancel Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

and this code in Form2:

```
Public Class Form2
    'if the Ok button is clicked, return a dialog result of OK
    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    End Sub
    'if the cancel button is clicked, return a dialog result of Cancel
    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
    End Sub
End Class
```

Depending on which button the user clicks in Form2, Form1 will either close or remain open.

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to post a comment on my answer and I'll be glad to direct you further.